# Does my base adapter implementation leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

So this my inner class of a base adapter implementation. Note it is for an expandable list view but I use the same process of instantiation for all my list views

```
    class GamesAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
    {

        private Context context;


        public GamesAdapter(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;

        }
    }
```

My question is , how do I dispose of this context because after some reading holding a context is a reference to activity so when I rotate the old instance may not be GC'ed thus a memory leak. Please help me

Comment: make inner class static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the screen orientation changes the system will (by default)  destroy the current activity and create a new one while giving you a chance to maintain its state. Cant you just set the context again  ? im not sure if your handling the config change yourself.

me personally, I'd just pass in getApplicationContext() anytime i need a context since it  does not depend on the activity lifecycle ( its not an activity context).  But  you can also get the context from a View in your getChildView() etc.

Further, if your list is going to be rebuilt on the config change anyway cant you just make its constructor take in the activity context you want ? that way it gets renewed ? So im not seeing where the leak would be yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you rotate the screen the Activity is destroyed but also your BaseExpandableListAdapter implementation. So Android will create a new instance of the Activity and a new instance of your adapter, you don't have to worry about it.